# Bitbucket-pipeline.yml does not read my Heroku environment variables

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, heroku-ci

I want to deploy my application to HEROKU when I push to master via my bitbucket repo. I have the `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` file set-up which doesn't seem to have any syntax errors.

But the build fails while reading my `$HEROKU_API_KEY`. This key is in my `.env` file and logs to the console when I log it from the `index.js` file.

The only feasible option is to copy the `api-key` and paste it into that line. But I don't really don't wanna do that.

*I am currently on `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` and `node v10.16.3`*

How do I solve this puzzle?

### Here is the yml file

```
# This is a sample build configuration for JavaScript.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/14UWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Defaults
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - npm install
          - npm test
    - step:
        name: create artifact
        script:
          - mkdir artefacts
          - tar -czf artefacts/my-app-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.tar.gz --exclude=./artefacts .
          - cp artefacts/* .
        artifacts:
          - my-app-*.tar.gz
    - step:
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.0.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              HEROKU_APP_NAME: "my-app"
              ZIP_FILE: "my-app-$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER.tar.gz"
              WAIT: "true" # Optional.
              DEBUG: "false" # Optional
```

### This is the build result

[image: bitbucket build result]

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Repository Variables in the repository settings to store environment variables. I don't think Bitbucket Pipelines work with .env files. You can find more details about using Pipelines environment variables here https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html.

Comment: Thank you, I found it, there is a deployment settings section in bitbucket that allows you to enter your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. bitbucket sets environment variable from the online repository, it doesn't use the local environment variables in the local repo.

To access this, you have to go to the `repository` -> `settings` -> `deployment`

Bitbucket provides 3 default build environments:
- testing
- staging
- production

You can add environment variables for any of the above environments.

Thanks to Alexander Zhukov for providing heads-up.